# Export Material UI Table in excel/csv format

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

In my web application I am using a Table from (material-ui/core/Table) is it possible to export it in excel or csv format? I cannot find anything from the documentation of material UI, except for using custom projects.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Material-UI Table API, it doesn't offer that functionality.

I suggest you use Material-UI DataGrid to render tables as it offers the functionality of downloading the table as a csv file.

Here's the link to the DataGrid which has the functionality implemented using GridToolbar: https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/export/

Answer (score 0):

first lets import the library,

```
import { ExportCsv, ExportPdf } from '@material-table/exporters';
```

After Importing add the below thing to the material table options,

```
        exportMenu: [{
          label: 'Export PDF',
          exportFunc: (cols, datas) => ExportPdf(cols, datas, 'myPdfFileName')
        }, {
          label: 'Export CSV',
          exportFunc: (cols, datas) => ExportCsv(cols, datas, 'myCsvFileName')
        }]
```